# ETL and analytics ready backend architecture

Tags: web-services, database-design, architecture, soa

Let's suppose I have retail website like amazon. Right now when I use ETL tool, my mobile application become inconsistent.
Could you suggest me some best data warehouse/ETL ready architecture which can be best fit for analysis purpose also and serving the main application also.

If there is something related with micro-service architecture then please suggest.

Please do provide reference also if any.
Thank you

Comment: Please specify the technology for your backend and mobile application

Comment: I'm using mysql and java....and native android for mobile app